# Bridging two interfaces with iproute2 doesn't work

Tags: linux, kernel, routing, bridge, iproute

I'm trying to create a bridge between eth0 and eth1 with iproute2, but there's always the error:

```
RTNETLINK answers: Operation not supported
```

when I use the command:`ip link add name br0 type bridge`.

But I read that you first need to change the kernel config here(Is this even right?):https://superuser.com/questions/232807/iproute2-not-functioning-rtnetlink-answers-operation-not-supported

Where do I find this kernel config file (I'm using micro core linux)?

Comment: Are you doing this as root / with `sudo`?

Comment: @Dubu I tried it as root and also as normal user with sudo, It was actually not supported, updated the post